# Facebook Logout causes logout from my application

Tags: javascript, facebook, logout, single-sign-on

I have created simple javascript widget where login happens using Facebook Single Sign On. It logins the person whenever he is logged in to facebook (after authorization for the first time). However, it also logs out the user when Facebook logout happens. I want the person to not get logged out when the person logs out of Facebook?

Suggest me what is the way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to keep a facebook connection going once they are logged out. The way around would be to create your own user tracking.

Once a user is logged in through facebook - store their information in a session (cookie,  table) and then rely only on that to check if this user is still logged in (you will need to implement your own logout too). This will work only if you use facebook as a login provider, if you need some interactions with facebook api that require login - they have to be logged in to facebook.