# FB.login is always asking my password (even if I'm already logged in)

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm playing with Facebook Javascript SDK in order to implement a Facebook Connect action. It's already working but the problem is that every time that I try to login again on my application the user has to reenter its facebook password.

I'm sure that there is an option to do this step without entering the password if you are already logged in in facebook (I have seen this in lots of web pages). But how? The documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ and even the source code does not explain how to do this:

"@param opts {Object} (*optional*) Options to modify login behavior."

My implementation right now is like this:

```
function login(){
  FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {

     $(".fb_login").hide();
     $(".fb_logout").show();

     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       register_user(response.id, response.name);
     });

   } else {
     alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
 }
```

And I call to FB.init like this:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Maybe it has to be a change in the FB.init or some kind of option while calling to FB.login. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Raimon Bosch.

Comment: Seems that the main problem is my logout action. When the user logs out from my application he logs out also from Facebook. That's why they need to reenter the password all the time. So the solution must be create a logout action a little bit more clean.

Comment: So you already know the answer to the question (namely, don't log out of Facebook when logging out of your application)? Then please add that as an answer and accept it. :-)

Comment: What is very suprising is why the hell your application needs to close the facebook session of a user? My application is my application it has nothing to do with facebook except for login. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/ "FB.logout will log the user out of both your site and Facebook"

Comment: Seems that the correct solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941334/facebook-logout-causes-logout-from-my-application

Answer (score 1):

There is a method [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) which you can use to check if user is already loggedin:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    //you are loggedin 
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    //loggedin but not authorized your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: No this is ok. When I login I use this method to detect if the user is logged or not and it works. The problem is that the facebook connect popup is always asking for a password even if I'm already logged in in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 
[Force Web OAuth Reauthentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/) in your PP setting facebbok developer>Your App> facebook login > setting > set Force Web OAuth Reauthentication to NO